# OS X Lion: Web Sharing Can't Start

Tags: operating-systems, apache-http-server, osx-lion

It worked before, and I'm not sure when it stopped working, but I'm unable to start Web Sharing at the moment. Attempting to start it from the Sharing screen results in "Web Sharing Starting..." immediately followed by "Web Sharing: Off". I've tried reverting to the httpd.conf in /etc/apache2/original, but the result is the same.

I checked the config file with:

```
sudo apachectl configtest
```

It reports the following:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/sbin/httpd
  Reason: image not found
/usr/sbin/apachectl: line 90:  5740 Trace/BPT trap: 5       $HTTPD -t
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you referenced Postgres in httpd.conf, installed or uninstalled it recently?

Comment: I did install (and subsequently uninstall after it didn't install successfully) Postgres a few weeks ago; I don't recall making a change to the httpd.conf at that time, though.

Comment: It appears that this is the problem and resolution: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3243357?start=0&tstart=0.  It now works.

Comment: Please post this as an answer below, using the "Answer Your Question" button. That makes it easier for others to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this is the [problem and resolution](http://discussions.apple.com/thread/3243357?start=0&tstart=0):

> It appears `/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib` does not exist but `/usr/lib/libpq.5.3.dylib` does.
>
> Fix by creating a symbolic link from `/usr/lib/libpq.5.3.dylib` to `/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib`:
>
> ```
> sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libpq.5.3.dylib /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
> ```
>
> Going back to System Preferences -> Internet and Wireless -> Sharing clicking Web
>
> Sharing a couple of times turns Web Sharing on successfully!
>
> Going to `http://localhost/` displays the "It Works!" page.
>
> — [Azattis - OS X Lion PostgreSQL 8.4 Installation Problem](http://www.azattis.com/2011/07/os-x-lion-postgresql-84-install-problem.html)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.